# join is removing escape of escaped string

Tags: javascript

Why are the `\` removed in the `result` and how can I prevent this? I need to keep the escaped string as it is.

```
const result = [
  'TITLE=Frontend',
  'DESCRIPTION=The\ frontend\ application'
].join('\n')
```

Expected result is:

```
TITLE=Frontend
DESCRIPTION=The\ frontend\ application
```

*Update*

The other way would be to join the string and escape the complete string after joining. I think this would be even better...

Comment: Try printing the array before joining, you'll see that the backslashes were never there in the first place.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `join`, there is no backslash in the string resulting from the string literal `'DESCRIPTION=The\ frontend\ application'`. In a string literal, a backslash is an *escape character* (a metacharacter), not a literal character. What it does depends on the character(s) after it. In this case, the backslashes do nothing, because they escape spaces and `<escape><space>` results in just `<space>`. Try this to see the original string: `console.log('DESCRIPTION=The\ frontend\ application');`. More in [these results](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+backslash+in+string).

Comment: If you want a backslash in a string you're defining with a string literal, you have to escape it: `console.log('DESCRIPTION=The\\ frontend\\ application');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join()` isn't removing anything. The backslash isn't in the original strings. It's just escaping the spaces, but space doesn't require escaping.

You need to escape the backslash if you need it to be included in the string literally.

```js
const result = [
  'TITLE=Frontend',
  'DESCRIPTION=The\\ frontend\\ application'
].join('\n')

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Well done, but in addition he can use `String.raw` on original strings instead of manually add extra escape slash which might not be possible if these strings are dynamic ... 
`String.raw`The\ frontend\ application`
"The\\ frontend\\ application"`